# PHP Paypal API ExpressCheckout, i don't know what i sold in history details

Tags: php, api, paypal, express, checkout

I use express checkout API and payment works but in seller account history I don't know what I sold, item1 , item2, etc... don't appear in details for a sale.

*Sorry, it's in french but not realy important for understand*

In Payment details, i want see what product I sold like this: (sorry I can't post img or more link, i'm new)
i1278.photobucket.com/albums/y508/IDarkcide/cart_zpsc3ab6a39.png

When customer buy, they have this:
http://i1278.photobucket.com/albums/y508/IDarkcide/paypalcart_zps76b0e25e.png

But,in seller account i have this(don't know what i sold): http://i1278.photobucket.com/albums/y508/IDarkcide/paypaldetails_zps6eb8feb1.png

Someone can help me ?
Ask me if you want watch a specific part of my code!

ps: sorry for my english i'm french.

Comment: You should always post a sample of your code and your desired results.

Comment: I want something like this: http://i1278.photobucket.com/albums/y508/IDarkcide/cart_zpsc3ab6a39.png

Comment: And for a sample of my code i don't know what send. Because i don't know where is my problem, if a miss an option or something like this for the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your item details included in your SetExpressCheckout request, which is what makes them show up on the PayPal review page.  However, you must not have those same details included in your DoExpressCheckoutPayment request, which is why they're left out of the final transaction details.

You need to make sure to include all of those same details in DECP just like you did in SEC.

Comment: You have true, i only send PaymentDetails with total amount and i don't send PaymentDetailsItemType for DECP.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Andrew Angell , it's work!

I forgot this code :

```
   $itemTotal = new BasicAmountType();
   $itemTotal->currencyID = $getECResponse->GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails->PaymentDetails[0]->ItemTotal->currencyID;
   $itemTotal->value = $getECResponse->GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails->PaymentDetails[0]->ItemTotal->value;

   $taxTotal = new BasicAmountType();
   $taxTotal->currencyID = $getECResponse->GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails->PaymentDetails[0]->TaxTotal->currencyID;
   $taxTotal->value = $getECResponse->GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails->PaymentDetails[0]->TaxTotal->value;

   $paymentDetails->ItemTotal = $itemTotal;
   $paymentDetails->TaxTotal = $taxTotal;
   $paymentDetails->PaymentDetailsItem = $getECResponse->GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails->PaymentDetails[0]->PaymentDetailsItem;
```